# The outer body of my Nikon D7200 is damaged, repair?

Tags: nikon, repair, equipment-damage, hotshoe

I recently dropped my Nikon D7200 off a counter on to concrete due to my carelessness and not checking my tripod before turning around. My question for anyone is that if it is worth it to get the body repaired or wait until the camera is old enough/outdated to buy a new one. I love the speed and quality of the D7200; however, I do not wish to be spending $300+ to repair it when that was already half the price it took me to purchase it. The hot shoe is bent, part of the bottom is cracked, flash doesn't fully extend but still functions when pushed far enough. I'll include pictures if needed.

Comment: We can't tell you if anything is "worth it", it's up to you to work out if you want to spend money on something.

Comment: Is it insured? Have you got a quote on the repair bill?

Comment: If it's insured, this could be the way to go if you really want it to be pristine, however it could affect your premium, If you have insurance, I'd check out the terms and see if it's a viable option, but I wouldn't be so inclined to pay for the repair yourself unless its totally unusable.

Comment: @PhilipKendall i thought about it's worth and it works "fine" but just not to the standard that i'd like it to.

Comment: @CrazyDino no and.. no. i wish i got insurance on it but everything i had bought at the time had racked the bill up and i didn't want to spend more money where i didn't have to

Comment: @Alex it is not insurned and having insurance on a camera, on top of my other bills, is going to a pain for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question here really is, does it still work well enough to use.

It's never a nice thing to have to balance the cost versus the benefit of spending a lot on fixing something knowing that it will never be quite right, but I would turn this on its head slightly and see this as a possible benefit.

How worried are you going to be about damaging it further now it's already taken a knock? 
How much more do you trust the build quality if it's hit concrete and the optics are still usable?

What you have now is a camera with a crack in it, damaged hotshoe, and unless there's anything else functionally wrong with it, that's the extent of the serious issues.
If you like the camera, the only real problem here is the flash issue, so how often do you use the flash in general use?

If you can manage without it, then the camera is still fine to work with.

Personally, I'd advise getting some good quality tape, covering the cracks and just using it as it is.

To repair a body crack requires a new part - no amount of glue or filler and paint will ever make it seamless, and a reconditioning job would involve replacing the entire outer shell.

If you can bend the hotshoe back into shape sufficiently to stick another flash on it, then you can still use it perfectly well.

Sadly, selling anything with cosmetic damage is always going to take off a huge amount of the value, but to you, it's the difference between shooting pictures and not shooting pictures.

Just chalk this one up to experience, patch it back together and go enjoy your hobby.

When you can afford it, get another body and use the slightly damaged one as your backup, or as a camera for when you're out and about somewhere with more risk of further damage.

Comment: this was a great answer, thank you for the advice Alex

Comment: @Hydroxing You're welcome, and I do understand your frustration. Years ago, I managed to damage a MacBook Pro by dropping it, which put a bend into the casing. It didn't sit flat on a table, but repairing it would have meant a whole new lower case and though I could fix it, it would have cost about £300. I just stuck some rubber feet on the corners to stop it wobbling and used it as it was. It looked a mess, but I could still get work done with it.

Comment: @Hydroxing Fundamentally, this is a question of worth versus value. To you, the camera is incredibly valuable as it is the tool you use as a creative outlet. With a crack in it, it's worth is significantly lower, but if it still works, it's still just as valuable to you. I have a sigma lens with a peeling rubber coating on it which a friend gave me as he couldn't sell it for what it's worth in that condition. I've just covered it in clear tape and I have some £500 worth of lens which takes brilliant pictures. I'd never sell it as to me it's indispensable now.

Answer (score 0):

Well, overhaul or new purchase is your call and your budget. It sounds like it is pretty much trashed. So you have two options. Replace it, or take it to someone that can fix it. If it fell hard enough to bend the shoe it will never work like it used to. Get it fixed for $100 and sell it for $200. That offsets the cost of a new camera body.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of course is entirely up to you, but if you do spend the money repairing it will you be satisfied with the results knowing that the camera is not what it used to be.

I personally would be inclined to purchase a known working one and sell what  I have for spares or repair.